How to order number results by the last 3 digits but in groups of 10?
Is there a way I can get my query to order results via the last 3 digits in the number but in an order resembling "000, 010, 020, 030, 050, 060, 070, 080, 090, 001, 011, 021, 031, 041, 051, 061, 071, 081, 091, 002, 012, 022, 032" etc?
Order by
((cast(right(column name, 3) as int / 10) * 10), column name;

This just seems to order it randomly instead of in the order I'm looking for.

Not quite sure what order you have in mind. Are we supposed to read the numbers from right to left? (i.e. 001=100, 020 =20)

No. I want all results where the last 3 digits of the number are "000" then all of the results where the last 3 digits are "010" and so on.

Where would '100' be ordered?

@ThomA Why did you delete your answer?

Needs a RIGHT in there, and felt that it wasn't dissimilar enough from the others, @Charlieface . Not to mentioned we all assume that the values are a value integer value

@ThomA Is that not just ORDER BY YourColumn % 100, YourColumn % 10, YourColumn % 1000 And why shouldn't we assume so?

If the column is an integer: order by [column name] % 10, [column name] % 1000. If a string guaranteed to have at least 3 characters: order by RIGHT([column name], 1), RIGHT([column name], 3). If the column is a string and may have fewer that 3 characters,  you will need to add padding: order by RIGHT('0' + [column name], 1), RIGHT('000' + [column name], 3). Each of these will first sort by the rightmost column "xx0" .. "xx9" and then by the next two "00x", "01x", ..., "98x", "99x".  (Including the last digit in the order-by term has no effect. It is just simpler to include it.)

Your requirements were not clear, but I have assumed that "100", "110", ..., "980", and "990" all come before "001", "011" ... "991",  "002", "012", ... "992", ....  Is that correct?

"And why shouldn't we assume so?" Experience, @Charlieface . ;)

Your ordering is quite unique to say the least. Using your sample data here is one way to accomplish this.
create table SomeTable
(
    SomeVal varchar(20)
)

insert SomeTable
values
('000'), ('010'), ('020'), ('030'), ('050'), ('060'), ('070'), ('080'), ('090'), ('001'), ('011'), ('021'), ('031'), ('041'), ('051'), ('061'), ('071'), ('081'), ('091'), ('002'), ('012'), ('022'), ('032')

select SomeVal
from SomeTable
order by right(SomeVal, 1)
    , right(SomeVal, 2)
    , right(SomeVal, 3)


I bet the REVERSE function will serve a purpose here.
Order By 
    REVERSE([column name])

OR
Order By
    REVERSE(RIGHT([column name],3)

